# Realm , RXJava project does not recognise my intent. Activities have Name_ in manifest trying to understand why

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, realm, rx-java2

So this is a project that I got from someone and it worked perfect for half an year ,but changed my pc and everything went nuts.
So I know the project uses EventBus with rxjava , Realm and mosby MVP:
http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/mvp/

This is how my SplashScreen looks like:

```
package nl.dtt.refcom4all.ui.splash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import nl.dtt.refcom4all.App;
import nl.dtt.refcom4all.data.models.LocalUser;
import nl.dtt.refcom4all.ui.BaseMvpActivity;
import nl.dtt.refcom4all.ui.registration.RegisterActivity_;

public class SplashActivity extends BaseMvpActivity<ISplashView, ISplashPresenter> implements ISplashView {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getPresenter().start();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ISplashPresenter createPresenter() {
    return new SplashPresenter();
}

@Override
public void openRegister() {
    App
            .getLocalStorage()
            .getLocalUser()
            .subscribe(new Consumer<LocalUser>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(LocalUser localUser) throws Exception {
                    RegisterActivity_.intent(getContext()).mLocalUser(localUser).start();
                    finish();
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    RegisterActivity_.intent(getContext()).start();
                    finish();
                }
            });
}

@Override
public Context getContext() {
    return this;
}
}
```

I run gradlew assembleDebug and I get this:

```
 error: cannot find
symbol
import nl.dtt.refcom4all.ui.registration.RegisterActivity_;
                                    ^
 symbol:   class RegisterActivity_
 location: package nl.dtt.refcom4all.ui.registration
```

When doing:

```
Note: Creating DefaultRealmModule
```

Any ideea what might be causing this?

Also why the manifest has the classes like this:

Im trying'to figure out what is causing the issue so I know what exactly to look for

This is what error I get after removing those intents

```
  15:29:22.258 [Task worker for ':'] ERROR o.a.i.h.AndroidManifestFinder:148 - Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, using  generation folder [D:\Workspace\refcom4all-android\app\build\generated\source\apt\debug])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours, I did find a solution. I searched for my debug manifest, and after I found it, I forced the android annotation to use that path for the manifest:
Which means this in the android -> defaultConfig in build.gradle

```
javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = [
                    'androidManifestFile': 'app\\build\\intermediates\\merged_manifests\\debug\\AndroidManifest.xml'
            ]
        }
    }
```